# Which Protection Profiles required for EAL 1 test?

Tags: common-criteria

I have some question about PPs for EAL1 test.

1- Which PPs required for a **Router Devices** in EAL 1 test?We only need compliance with '*collaborative Protection Profile for Network Devices*' (aka NDcPP) or other PPs is required,such as '*[Router PP for Medium Robustness Environments](https://www.niap-ccevs.org/pp/pp_router_mr_v1.0.pdf)*' ?

2- If I need to compliance with Router PP, so the question is : EAL 1 test is a functionally test, but Router PP has requirements for Structurally and Methodically test, for example FCS_IKE_(EXP).1 in the page 61 of Router PP. well, Do I need certain requirements  instead of all requirements in Router PP? Which requirements is needed?

Thanks a lot for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a simple network device such as router, in 2016 you only need to claim NDcPP (collaborative Network Device Protection Profile) and nothing else.  PP (protection profile) you linked is no longer in use. NDcPP will include all functional (SFR) and assurance (SAR) components that you have to include in your ST (Security Target). NDcPP is evaluated at EAL1, but you don't include explicit claim of EAL assurance with it.
2. NDcPP requires exact compliance, that is you can't add or remove requirements and conforming is all or nothing deal. The only exception is EP (extended packages) such as firewall and SIP server that are technology-specific. You can find full list of EPs here: https://www.niap-ccevs.org/Profile/PP.cfm by searching for "Extended Package for...".